# Apollo + GraphQL: Fragment on interface works for one concrete type but not on the other

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have an interface `CommonUser` with `PublicUser` and `User` that implements `CommonUser`.

I have two endpoints: one for `PublicUser` and one for `User`:

```
interface CommonUser {
  id
  ...
}

type User implements CommonUser {
  id 
  ...
}

type PublicUser implements CommonUser {
  id
  ...
}


extend type Query {
 publicUser(id: ID!): PublicUser
}

extend type Mutation {
 fetchCreateUser(id: ID!): User!
}
```

On the front end, I want to use a fragment to share common fields,

```
const COMMON_FIELDS = gql`
fragment CommonUserFields on CommonUser {
  id
  ...
}
`

const FETCH_CREATE_USER = gql`
${COMMON_FIELDS}
mutation fetchCreateUser {
  fetchCreateUser(id: 123) {
    ...CommonUserFields
    ...
  }
}
`

const PUBLIC_USER = gql`
${COMMON_FIELDS}
query publicUser {
  publicUser(id: 123) {
    ...CommonUserFields
    someOtherField
  }
}
`
```

When I use the `FETCH_CREATE_USER` mutation, it works as intended, returning all the common user fields.

However, when I use the `PUBLIC_USER` query, it only returns `someOtherField` in the response.

I have verified on the backend resolver that `graphQLFields(info)` does contain all the requested fields, and the object being returned contains all requested fields.

Comment: tested in playground?